# Web Api POST method Getting NULL Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a POST API which accepts an object for class A. Here is how the class A looks like

```
[DataContract]
class A {
   [DataMember]
   public Dictionary<string, string> a { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public Dictionary<string, B> b { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class B {
    [DataMember]
    public IList<string> c { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IList<IList<string>> d { get; set; }    
}
```

When I'm sending an object of the same class from my client using the HTTPClient PostJsonAsAsync

```
client.PostJsonAsAsync(string.Empty, objectOfClassA)
```

I'm not sure how in only some cases the API is getting null object. I'm not sure if it's a serialization issue or a deserialization issue? Is there anyway we can determine where the problem could be?

Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ReturnObject PostMethod([FromBody] A a)
{
       //business logic
}
```

P.S.: I cannot dump the value of A as it's a PII information.

Comment: Can you post your Web API here?Actually, if you use JSON, DataContract and DataMember are not necessary.

Comment: Which some cases the API is getting null object?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The problem is I don't know that. If I knew that the question would have been more specific around the problem if I didn't find it stackoverflow already.

Comment: @KhoaNguyen updated

Comment: Are you sure that`objectOfClassA` is not null in those cases?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes 100%